# Overflow in the division on the top affecting properties of division just below it

Tags: css, html, overflow

I am new to CSS. I have created 4 main `divs`, `header`, `bodybg`, `nav` and main content.

I defined properties for `#nav div`, and it looked great. Now I wanted to create a jQuery slider in the `div` above it, i.e. `#bodybg`, but when I as a first step create a `div #wrap` inside the `#bodybg` and try to put 3 images on it, my nav bar is affected: it no longer has its properties and looks like a plain list of items.

Now when I remove 2 images our of 3, it becomes fine. In CSS for `#wrap` I added `overflow:hidden`  but that rather makes `#nav` totally vanished or hidden.

The working state of my project: http://estheticdentalcare.co.in.white.mysitehosted.com/HTMLpage.htm

That was before I added the `#wrap div` inside the `#bodybg` and three images in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i'm not sure that whats you are trying to do but if you want to do. But here is a link.

To make sure that all image div are on the same line, make them align left. And make sure youyr math are ok. If you have more width than the actual container div it will jump on two line and if you have overflow hidden the image will just be outside your container.

http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/W5n4Y/1/